# glibc detected double free or corruption

Tags: c++, glibc

I'm having a glibc detected problem. I have researched a way to solve this however it seems like the correct solution is to free whatever I have allocated. However, even though I do this, I still receive a memory map print on my output screen.

```
class TestDepth{
    gameStatus temp;
public:
    TestDepth(gameStatus &currentGameState)
    {
        temp = currentGameState;

        free(&temp);
    }
};
```

I only get this error when I place the `temp=currentGameState` line. But once I comment that out, it works fine.

Comment: `free` only what you `malloc`ated. `free(&` is usually a bug.

Comment: And in C++, there's almost never a need to use `free` (or `malloc`/`calloc`).

Answer (score 5):

> As you can see, I'm having a glibc detected problem. I have research a way to solve this however it seems like the correct solution is to free whatever I have allocated.

You aren't allocating anything. You shouldn't be freeing anything.

Comment: Ohhhh!! Kk. So I need to allocate first before I copy over the information?

Comment: @RommelAlonzo : No! The space for the data member `temp` already exists because the instance that contains it already exists. A constructor populates an already existing object. There is nothing to allocate.

Comment: Ok, so what would I need to do what I want to copy over the information that is being brought over from the currentGameStatus object?

Answer (score 0):

`temp = currentGameState;`

This will call `gameStatus`'s assignment operator(either default or your version). If the default assignment operator is called, then a bit wise assignment would have done. This is dangerous if `currentGameState` object has some heap resources in it. If there is an assignment operator for `gameStatus`, hopefully you have done the required deep copy.

Either way you are not supposed to use `free` to deallocate the object `temp`. One reason is that is not the right way to free an object. Another reason is this might try to free something which is not allocated by `malloc`.

Comment: `temp = currentGameState;` does not call the `gameStatus` copy constructor. The data member `temp` has already been default constructed by the point this line of code is executed. The statement `temp = currentGameState;` instead calls the `gameStatus` assignment operator. To call the copy constructor, one would need to put `temp(currentGameState)` in the constructor's initialization list.

Comment: @DavidHammen, you are right, `temp` would have default constructed by the time body of the constructor executes. I just did not think of that! corrected my answer, thanks...

Answer (score -1):

You're not freeing what you think you are freeing. When you assign to temp you are assigning to a copy of gameStatus - which did not come from the heap. You are not deleting the version of GameStatus that is passed in as an argument, you are deleting a copy.

Skip the assignment to temp and just do

```
free( &currentGameState );
```

Comment: You need `()` here. `free` is a normal C function. It's not the same as C++ operator `delete`.

Comment: Who knows if `temp` is on the stack?  All we know is it's in the same place as the `TestDepth` instance.

Comment: You're right. But you can be sure that temp is not at an address given by the heap, which was really my point. I'll fix the answer

Comment: -1. Skip the assignment to temp? This is a constructor. The thing to skip is the `free` statement.

Comment: I think he want to delete the argument passed in the the constructor, and keep the constructed class alive. I'm sure this is a scrap from a larger function. I would bet that the intention is, make a temp copy of the passed in argument, use it to construct TestDepth, and then delete the argument. But he's deleting the temporary that should probably not be created as a class member in the first place.

Comment: @David: also his question is not about the design. Which we can't glean from something so short - but why free is failing.

Comment: You can't guarantee that `&temp` isn't an address given by malloc, but that's not the point.  The point is that you can't guarantee that it *is* given by malloc.